# What is the best way to call async methods using reactiveui + throttle

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm trying to solve my first task using Rx + ReactiveUI and am looking for best practices to solve a task, showing a input box that will show up suggestions as soon as the user starts typing.

According to the following code sample, what is the best way to load suggestions asynchronosly? Using `Subscribe` or using `Select Many`? Or is there a better way to do this beneth these two?

```
     this.SearchTerms = this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SearchTerm)
            .Throttle(SuggestionThrottle, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Value()
            .SelectMany(async s => await this.LoadSearchSuggestions(s));  // 1st Possibility

        this.SearchTerms.Subscribe(this.LoadSearchSuggestions);           // 2nd Possibility
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must call `Subscribe` either way.

Queries in Rx use lazy evaluation, which means that merely defining a query does not start it. Lazy evaluation allows you to build a query by applying operators conditionally, to define a query only once and store it in a field for later, or to pass a reference around without causing any side effects until you call `Subscribe`.

Without calling `Subscribe` your query will remain inactive.

`Subscribe` activates the query by passing to the observable your `IObserver<T>`, or you can use its overloads that allow you to supply `OnNext`, `OnError` and/or `OnCompleted` handlers individually, which Rx converts into an `IObserver<T>` for you. It is the `IObserver<T>` that receives the query's notifications.

There is a parameterless overload of `Subscribe` that internally uses a silent observer, with the intention of starting your query for its side effects only. For example, in your case if you were to use `SelectMany` to do all of the work of loading the suggestions and you had no need for a separate `IObserver<T>`, then you would start the query by calling the parameterless overload of `Subscribe`.

In most cases you shouldn't use the parameterless overload of `Subscribe`. The point of `Subscribe` is that the `IObserver<T>` (or the individual handlers) that you pass to it are intended to cause the side effects of your query. By only causing side effects in either `Subscribe` or, for instance, the `Do` operator, a query is much easier to reason about and to maintain.

However, there is one fairly common scenario where using the parameterless overload of `Subscribe` makes sense: If the side effects of your query are caused by an asynchronous method, then using `SelectMany` along with the parameterless overload of `Subscribe` is best.

The reason is simple: `SelectMany` is the sequential composition operator, which enables you to call an asynchronous method as a sequential step inside your query. Therefore, `SelectMany` ties the cancellation of the subscription to the cancellation of your asynchronous computation. Disposing of a subscription (represented by the `IDisposble` that is returned from the call to `Subscribe`) causes the `CancellationToken` provided by special asynchronous overloads of the `SelectMany` operator to be signaled for cancellation. Your asynchronous method can monitor the `CancellationToken` to exit its computation early.

There aren't any overloads of `Subscribe` that accept an asynchronous observer, whereby `OnNext` returns a `Task`. But even if you were to call a void-returning asynchronous method in your `OnNext` handler, your asynchronous method wouldn't be signaled when the subscription is disposed.

Note that both of your code samples are slightly wrong anyway. The first example has no need for the `async` and `await` keywords. As stated above, there are special overloads of `SelectMany` that accept a `Task<T>`-returning *selector* function, and additional overloads that provide a `CancellationToken` to that function. You should probably be using the latter.

Your second example shouldn't compile, presuming that `LoadSearchSuggestions` returns `Task`. (Unless the ReactiveUI library or some other library that you're referencing is providing an overload of `Subscribe` that accepts a `Task`-returning function, in which case you'll have to consult their documentation.)

Barring the latter, and assuming that the rest of your query is correct, here's what you should do:

```
this.SearchTerms = this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.SearchTerm)
  .Throttle(SuggestionThrottle, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
  .Value()
  .SelectMany(LoadSearchSuggestionsAsync)
  .Subscribe();
```

where `LoadSearchSuggestionsAsync` is defined like this:

```
async Task<Unit> LoadSearchSuggestionsAsync(string term, CancellationToken cancel)
{
  ...
  return Unit.Default;
}
```

Note that [Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.unit.aspx) represents *void* in Rx. It's required because an asynchronous method that returns a non-generic `Task` cannot be used with `SelectMany`. If you have actual data to return instead, then simply replace `Unit` with the type of your data. Then you can also pass an `OnNext` handler to `Subscribe` and do something with the return value, such as logging.

Comment: That is one of the best Rx related answers I've seen in a long time.  Thank you for increasing my understanding.

Comment: Um, could you please just document everything on the internet?  That would be awesome.  This is really helpful...